# Starting RabbitMQ server in Docker (Colima) on Mac Silicon (M1)?

Tags: docker, macos, rabbitmq

I'm trying to start RabbitMQ 3.10 from Docker running on MacOSX on Apple Silicon (M1). In Linux, I could just do:

```
docker run --rm --name my-rabbit rabbitmq:3.10.18-management
```

And I can see in the console that everything seems to boot as it should:

```
023-03-02 13:57:33.756849+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags: list of feature flags found:
2023-03-02 13:57:33.762401+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] classic_mirrored_queue_version
2023-03-02 13:57:33.762435+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] classic_queue_type_delivery_support
2023-03-02 13:57:33.762462+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] implicit_default_bindings
2023-03-02 13:57:33.762484+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] maintenance_mode_status
2023-03-02 13:57:33.762501+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] quorum_queue
2023-03-02 13:57:33.762522+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] stream_queue
2023-03-02 13:57:33.762537+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] user_limits
2023-03-02 13:57:33.762554+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] virtual_host_metadata
2023-03-02 13:57:33.762571+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags: feature flag states written to disk: yes
2023-03-02 13:57:33.903041+00:00 [notice] <0.44.0> Application syslog exited with reason: stopped
2023-03-02 13:57:33.903117+00:00 [notice] <0.223.0> Logging: switching to configured handler(s); following messages may not be visible in this log output
2023-03-02 13:57:33.909335+00:00 [notice] <0.223.0> Logging: configured log handlers are now ACTIVE
2023-03-02 13:57:33.993055+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> ra: starting system quorum_queues
2023-03-02 13:57:33.993109+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> starting Ra system: quorum_queues in directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/parkster-itest@f77e2b1ba2e8/quorum/parkster-itest@f77e2b1ba2e8
2023-03-02 13:57:34.018706+00:00 [info] <0.259.0> ra system 'quorum_queues' running pre init for 0 registered servers
2023-03-02 13:57:34.022754+00:00 [info] <0.260.0> ra: meta data store initialised for system quorum_queues. 0 record(s) recovered
..
```

On Mac however, I usually need to add `--platform linux/x86_64`, but this doesn't seem to work for RabbitMQ 3.10:

```
docker run --rm --platform linux/x86_64 --name my-rabbit rabbitmq:3.10.18-management
```

I get no logs printed to the console at all, including no error message, but the container just stops after a second or so:

```bash
$ time docker run --rm --platform linux/x86_64 --name my-rabbit rabbitmq:3.10.18-management
docker run --rm --platform linux/x86_64 --name my-rabbit   0.02s user 0.01s system 1% cpu 1.411 total
```

Running an older version of RabbitMQ seems to work though:

```bash
docker run --rm --platform linux/x86_64 --name my-rabbit rabbitmq:3.8.9
```

How can I get version 3.10 or later of RabbitMQ to start on Docker on Mac M1?

Comment: Try the `linux/arm64/v8` platform for Apple silicon all use the arm64 architecture.  https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/rabbitmq/3.10.18-management/images/sha256-99788ade7ad567077696e49314f55fb40175fed7eeeb53505b7351f620fcf96e?context=explore

Comment: That seems to work, thank you! Maybe you should write it as an answer?

Comment: Glad it works! I just wanted to clarify also that without the platform flag it does not work on your M1?  Theoretically it should be automatically choosing the correct arm64/v8 image without the flag.

Comment: Oh, you're right! It seems to work fine without the flag as well ‍♂️ My bad, sorry. I'll leave the question here anyways if other people make the same mistake as me.